# How to pass javascript/cordova value to jsf Managed-Bean.

Tags: javascript, jsf, cordova

how to pass javascript/cordova value to jsf Managed-Bean. 
i will edit this value in JSF-Bean and return it to javascript.
i need this for my cordova application. That works fine without problem in PHP. In PHP i can receive and request values bi-directional in both sides javascript <--> PHP. 
But my result must be in jsf.

my javascript -phonegap - cordova code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script>
    var xmlhttp;

    window.onload = function(){ 
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', init, false);
    }

    function init() {
        document.getElementById('btnGetTextvalue').addEventListener('click', getData, false);
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = processReturn;
    }


    function getData(){
        url="http://localhost:8080/PhoneGapProjectWithJSF/faces/index.xhtml";
        url += "?thisIsMyValue="+document.getElementById('myText').value;
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function processReturn(){
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

    }
</script>
```

```
  <body>
      <label for="myText">Wert Eingeben:</label>
      <input type="text" size="30" maxlenght="40" id="myText"/><br/>
      <input type="button" value="Pass Value" id="btnGetTextvalue"/>
      <div id=result></div>
  </body>
```

my ManagedBean Code:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "phoneGapProjectWithJSF")
@RequestScoped
public class PhoneGapProjectWithJSF implements Serializable {

  @ManagedProperty(value="#{param.thisIsMyValue}")
  private String neuvalue;

  public PhoneGapProjectWithJSF() {
  }

  public String getNeuvalue() {
      System.out.println(neuvalue);
      return neuvalue;
  }

  public void setNeuvalue(String neuvalue) {
      System.out.println(neuvalue);
     this.neuvalue = neuvalue;
  }
```

my index.xhtml:

```
 --------------
 <h:form>
       <h:outputText value="#{phoneGapProjectWithJSF.neuValue}"/>
 </h:form>
```

Comment: Where is the value you want to pass to the backing bean?

Comment: the value comes from Internet-Browser URL. 

for example: 

http://localhost:8080/....../index.xhtml?thisIsMyValue=helloWorld